# Powershell: reference all the scripts contained in some folder

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to reference in Powershell all the scripts contained in some folder? Something like:

```
."$PSScriptRoot\helpers\*.ps1"
```

I'm building types dynamically using:

```
New-Object -TypeName "$($fixture)Runner";
```

and I really want to reinforce convention over configuration, by setting all the types under that "helpers" folder.

Is that possible?

If I use the asterisk as a kind of regex then Powershell is not able to find the types I'm trying to instantiate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference the code in the files you can "Dot Source" them:

```
Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\helpers\*.ps1" | ForEach-Object{. $_.FullName}
```